# Div inside a flex container wont shrink when inside a `media only screen and (max-width: 430px)` thing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to make a website responsive but flex containers wont shrink. I have tried setting the `width` and  `height` of the flex-box element but not all of them will change. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdAQu.png) is what the flex-container looks normally. and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khLiJ.png) is what it looks like when the width of the screen is smaller that 430px The image witch is part of the flex-container will resize properly but not the div with the text witch is weird since i can resize it normally if i just change its width outside the `@media only screen and (max-width: 430px)`

**HTML**

```
   <div id="flex-stuff">
     <div class="pr_cont">
      <a href="#"><img id="project_img" src="images/img04.png" alt="stuff"></a>
      <div class="project_div">
        <p id="project_textA">Nascetur nunc varius commodo</p><br><br>
        <p id="project_textB">Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p><br><br>
        <a href="#" id="more_box" style="background-color: #82CEC6;">View more</a>
      </div>

        <div class="pr_cont">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="pr_cont">
        ...
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#flex-stuff {
display: flex;
justify-content:space-around;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pr_cont {
margin: 1% 1%;
width: 98%;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 400px;
}
#project_img {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; 
}
.project_div {
background-color: #333;
height: 250px;
flex: 1;
width: 400px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
} 
#project_textA {
margin-top: -4px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
color: white;
text-align:center;
padding-top: 30px;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 400;
}
#project_textB {
margin: 0;
font-size: 18px;
color: gray;
text-align: center;
}
#more_box {
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: white;
width: 10%;
margin: 0 5%;
background-color: #bd00ff;
padding: 20px 36%;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The problem is not that the I can't change the div to make it smaller. i can do that but not in `@media only screen and (max-width: 420px)` thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a `display: inline;` in a flex container. And the solution was to specify the `display: block;` on the `@media only screen and (max-width: 430px)` stuff.